# element.scrollTo api not working when adding behavior param

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, polaris

element.scrollTo api not working when adding behavior param

code:

```
scrollRef.scrollTo({
  top: 100,
  behavior: 'smooth', // no scroll when add behavior
})
```

Is it caused by using the Modal component of `@shopify/polaris`?

Does anyone know why behavior params will cause the api(scrollTo) not working?

Answer (score 0):

It's called

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

Comment: It has no effect.
As long as add behavior param to the option, it will not scroll.